# Android: JOSNObject parsing and simultaneously parsing XML and adding them to the list view

Tags: android, json, xml-parsing

I'm developing an application in which I'm getting `JSON` response from a URL. In that `JSON`response I have to parse `JSONObject` first. And, then I have to parse XML content in the `JSONObject`. Here is the sample of `JSON` response that I'm getting:

```
{
"output": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Results>\n    <Feed prov=\"dmoz\">\n        <ResultSet id=\"webListings\" source=\"DMOZ\">\n            <Listing description=\" - A bike shop in Brisbane. Stocks mountain bikes, road bikes, and BMX bikes.\n                    \" rank=\"1\" siteHost=\"http://www.lifecycle.net.au/\" title=\"Lifecycle Bike Shop\">\n                <ClickUrl type=\"body\">http://www.lifecycle.net.au/</ClickUrl>\n            </Listing>\n            <Listing description=\" - Videos and pictures taken of both sport bikes and dirt bikes.\n                    \" rank=\"2\" siteHost=\"http://roadanddirt.com/\" title=\"Road and Dirt\">\n                <ClickUrl type=\"body\">http://roadanddirt.com/</ClickUrl>\n            </Listing>\n</Results>"
}
```

Here is my Java code for parsing the API and getting `XML` in a `String`:

```
        HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("API here");
        ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        // get xml string form jsonObject
        String str_xml = json.getString("output");
```

I have parsed the `JSONObject` and now getting XML as a whole in a `String`, now I have to parse the whole XML and fix those in the listview, category wise. Please help me in parsing the `XML` and fixing those into listview. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get xml string from current json as :

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your json response");

 // get xml string form jsonObject

 String str_xml=json.getString("output");

 // now convert str_xml to xml document for xml parsing 
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
 inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str_xml));
 Document doc = db.parse(inStream); //<<< get xml Document here
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I'm getting this output from the URL. Can you tell me how to get this from the URL. I'm totally confused here.

Comment: @Anupam : what do u mean by *I'm getting this output from the URL. Can you tell me how to get this from the URL*  ? if you are getting it from URL then it's fine . just pass response string in JSONObject method

Comment: @Anupam : ok use [HTTP GET Request with HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-get-request-with-httpclient) for getting data from server , [Get the content from a HttpResponse](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-the-content-from-a-httpresponse-or-any-inputstream-as-a-string) for reading response and then pass string in `JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your json response");` to convert jsonobject

Comment: @Anupam what do you really want..whether to convert json to xml or anythign else......

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK - Up vote for your help, and I have edited my question, please check.

Comment: @Pragnani - Please see the edited question, hope you will understand my requirement.

Comment: @Anupam : friend this is not right way to ask question . now u are asking other question by editing it . u will need to make new question for next problem if u have any issue in xml parsing

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK - My bad, will do that if I'm having any problem.

Comment: @Anupam : yes great u have updated whole question with title. ok remember it for next time to get good and quick response to answer. have u try to parse xml?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK - Ya, was doing that. If I'm getting any problem regarding that, will make a new question and ask.

Comment: @Anupam : can u finish current question by marking it as answer for the previous problem and if u have any issue then leave me comment or make new question.Thanks